# virtualhost: doing http and https bad browser rendering

Tags: linux, apache2, virtualhost

I've the exactly the same config file for http virtualhost and the rendering of browser is ok. I've added (debian) new https virtualhost to /etc/apache/site-available but the rendering of browsers has incorrect.

You can show both sites going:

```
http://www.mokaccino.it/index.php (works)
https://www.mokaccino.it/index.php (bad)

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerSignature Off
ServerAdmin info@example.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
DocumentRoot /home/example.com/

suPHP_Engine on
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5
suPHP_AddHandler x-httpd-php

suPHP_ConfigPath /home/example.com/
<Directory /home/example.com/>
Options -Includes -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -ExecCGI +MultiViews
AllowOverride none
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /home/example.com/logs/error.log
CustomLog /home/example.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both http and https work fine. The only problem is that you have a self signed https certificate, so browser gives you warnings about it. You can try it with curl:

```
curl -v -k https://www.mokaccino.it/index.php

* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=IT; ST=Milano; L=Legnano; O=pineappleweb.it; OU=pineappleweb.it; CN=pineappleweb.it; emailAddress=info@pineappleweb.it
*    start date: 2013-07-04 12:47:19 GMT
*    expire date: 2033-06-29 12:47:19 GMT
*    issuer: C=IT; ST=Milano; L=Legnano; O=pineappleweb.it; OU=pineappleweb.it; CN=pineappleweb.it; emailAddress=info@pineappleweb.it
*    SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
```